# how to get the frequency of a pair of item in a dataframe in python or SQL

Tags: python

my date is like this

```
d = {'name':['a','b','c','a','c','a','b','a','b','d'],'class_no.':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4]}
x = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
display(x)
```

I want to know how many time two person has been in the same class? for example,
**a** and **b** are in class together for **1**,**3** and **4**. **a** and **c** are in class together for **1** and **2**. 
So (a,b) =3, (a,c)=2.

IS there a way to use pandas or SQL to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Does the data have to be in a dataframe? You could get the answer from the 'd' dictionary, alone

Comment: yes, it has to be in a dataframe

Comment: Okay sure. And do you want results for the whole dataframe?

Comment: yes, I do want the result for the whole dataframe

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you could self join the table and count the pairs. Note: I'm restricting the pairs so that the first item is always smaller than the second in order to avoid double results (`(a,b)` and `(b,a)`):

```sql
SELECT   a.name, b.name, COUNT(*)
FROM     mytable a
JOIN     mytable b ON a.class_no = b.class_no and a.name < b.bame
GROUP BY a.name, b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mureiniks SQL-answer, here is the pandas translation:

```
df = x.merge(x, on='class_no.')
df = df[df['name_x'] < df['name_y']]
df.groupby(['name_x', 'name_y']).size()
```